# Is Geolocation using IP a good measure to find the location of a computer

Tags: geolocation, ip

I just went through a couple of posts on Geolocation using IP address. Using IP addresses would just give the location of the ISP, databases would get outdated and also proxies should be considered.

I tried to know the location of an ip address using the api: http://api.hostip.info.  But it returned me unknown location.

As IP address does not provide reliable information, is there any other better ways to locate the position of a computer. Combining IP address with anything else or using MAC address to do the same.

Comment: afaik mac address doesn't leak out beyond the same network

Comment: not only that, but how would you associate mac addresses with geographical locations? ask hardware manufacturers which mac-address-range LAN adapters they sold to which wholesale suppliers, and then ask them which retailers they sold them to, and then hope that everyone buys from their local retailer?

Comment: @Anycorn, technically you can use wifi mac-addresses for geolocation.  As an example, [Google maps does this](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/04/22/google_streetview_logs_wlans/)... any time I'm at a hotspot in a cafe and fire up google maps on the ipad, it zeros in on my precise location within 15 seconds... and I don't have a cellular modem in my ipad

Comment: @SyncMaster, "good measure to find location" with what kind of precision?

Comment: @MikePennington It is considerably easier to find the city/ISP address. But I would like to narrow down to a specific address or  nearby locations.

Comment: I am just exploring how Googlemaps does the same. Are there any other techniques involved.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [HTML5 Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). Although I would not expect the API to be always present. So the IP address way could be used as a fall-back mechanism.

In our own online shops, I use the IP address approach, too, to determine the country where a user is ordering from.

Answer (score 0):

No. MAC address has no correlation with location and if you're not running on the user's computer or network you don't have access to that anyway. What else you can use depends on what information you have access to. If you're a web page then there isn't a whole lot you can do. If you're running on the user's computer, you may be able to get a list of local wi-fi hotspots, which can be correlated to location - Google does this - but not all computers have wi-fi. If you're running on a cell phone, you obviously have GPS. There isn't any other information you can use though.